# Does C# have an equivalent to #pragma pack in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

C# provides StructLayoutAttribute.Pack, but its behaviour is "every member gets at least the specified alignment whether it wants it or not", whereas the behaviour of #pragma pack in C++ is "every member gets the alignment it wants, unless it wants more than the specified alignment, in which case it's not guaranteed to get more than that".

Is there a way to cause the layout of a struct in C# to be the same as the layout of a similar struct in C++ with a specific #pragma pack, other than using StructLayout( LayoutKind.Explicit ) and FieldOffset on each member, or inserting unused padding members?

Comment: Can you provide a code example illustrating the difference you're seeing and why it's causing a problem? StructLayout.Pack has always covered my needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After experimenting with StructLayout.Pack, it appears that it does indeed do exactly the same thing as #pragma pack in C++. Believing the MSDN documentation for StructLayout.Pack (which claimed the behaviour described in my original post) was a mistake.